# limit to minus infinity

Tags: limits

> Determine $\lim_{a \to - \infty} (\sqrt{a^2+a} + a)$.

So using wolframalpha I found out the limit is $-\dfrac{1}{2}$, but I can't seem to figure out how to evaluate this limit. Can anyone give me any tips on how to change this expression so I can evaluate this limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{a^2+a}-a}{\sqrt{a^2+a}-a}$. Then simplify and make sure that when you take things in/out of square roots, you are very careful with sign!

Comment: I keep ending up with $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1}-1}$, so it seems I messed up the sign somewhere.

Comment: @ozgurl When you take $a^2$ out of the square root it becomes $|a|$ which is...

Comment: $-a$ for negative $a$?

Comment: @ozgurl Exactly! So then you should get $\frac{1}{-\sqrt{1}-1}=-\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Negative numbers are trouble, it is good to stay away from them.

Let $b=-a$. We want 
$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\sqrt{b^2-b}-b.$$
Now do the usual multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{b^2-b}+b$.

Comment: I end up with $-\dfrac{1}{2}$. But if you change the sign of the variable and the limit, is the answer the same?

Comment: The limit of $f(a)$ as $a\to-\infty$ is the same as the limit of $f(-b)$ as $b\to\infty$. This kind of change of variable is quite common.  Note that it is perfectly possible to find the limit without the change of variable. The only problem is that the risk of error is greater.